# image processing

Tags: iphone

how to control multiple UIImageview actions by using a single uislider in iphone sdk? Actions like hue,contrast,brightness,sacturation,sharpness.

Any sample codes or tutorials. Kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the pixels array of your UIImageView. To example (there are a lot of other ways too) with CGContextRef

```
CGContextRef context = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:yourView.image.CGImage];
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (context);

size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(yourView.image.CGImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(yourView.image.CGImage);


for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
  for (int x=0; x<width; x++) {
    int pos = y*width + x;
    int argb = data[pos];
    int r = (argb >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g = (argb >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b =  argb        & 0xff;
// do here your transformations
    data[pos] = (0xFF<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
  }
}
```

A simple transformation would be the brightness to example:

```
r = (int) (r + brightness);
g = (int) (g + brightness);
b = (int) (b + brightness);
if(r>=255) r=255;
if(g>=255) g=255;
if(b>=255) b=255;
```